# I want to add a watermark and text using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg. I want to add a text and image on a video using PHP.
I can add image correctly but I can't add a text to it.

My code:

```php
$command = "ffmpeg -i ".$dest_path." -i 2.jpeg ";
$command .= " -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v]";
$command .= " overlay=25:25\""; 
$str = rand();
$result = hash("sha256", $str);
$command .= " -c:a copy video/".$result.".mp4";
system($command)
```

Comment: What's the error message? (Show the output of the ffmpeg command).

Comment: i don't have errors but i don't know how to combine the image and text together

Comment: ffmpeg -i ".$dest_path."  -vf  "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text="aya":fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4        this is my  code to add a text on  the video can i combine the 2 codes together ?

Comment: Update the question instead, please. People will not read all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add the drawtext after the overlay, separated by a comma.

```
$command .= " overlay=25:25,drawtext=...\"";
```